# I am trying to completely remove an element from a website. Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to remove the arrows from www.redditp.com. I *think* the issue I am having is that the inner HTML of these divs don't actually contain anything so I need to delete the actual element (I can't find how to do that). But I could be completely wrong. Here is my code.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Redditp Button Disabler",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Disable ugly buttons on Redditp.",
  "permissions": ["https://redditp.com/"],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
        "http://redditp.com/*"],
        "js": ["main.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
document.getElementById('nextButton').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('prevButton').innerHTML = '';
```

Can anybody find a way to get this working for me? Thanks guys.

Comment: `var prev = document.getElementById('nextButton'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked, thanks though.

Comment: Actually I reloaded the extention a few times and it decided to work! Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Just another day with the DOM API, glad I could help. Please consider writing an elaborate answer about how the code snippet I posted solves the issue and then accepting it so people with the issue will know what worked and how you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment has solved my issue. My guess was correct, the issue was that it was jsut an icon that I was trying to remove, therefore the div was empty. the new main.js is as follows.

main.js

```
var prev = document.getElementById('prevButton'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
var prev = document.getElementById('nextButton'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
var prev = document.getElementById('navboxContents'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
var prev = document.getElementById('titleDiv'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
var prev = document.getElementById('controlsDiv'); prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
```

I finished up what I was trying to remove too. So now, when you load the page, all the useless ui elements are deleted. Remember, you need to but the ID in the brackets, not the class, it won't work if you put the class in.

Once again, thanks Ben for the help.